# Always render certain Wicket HeaderItem after all other HeaderItems of specific type

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I have a custom Wicket Behaviour (`RegisterBehaviour`) which can be attached to various Wicket components to add multiple JaveScript-Snippets event handlers to them via a (OnDomReady-)HeaderItem in `RegisterBehaviour.renderHead(Component, IHeaderResponse)`.

Now I have the requirement to trigger one of these events right after the page has been loaded to initialise all components with a certain computed value. To do that, I thought could add another Wicket Behaviour (`TriggerBehaviour`) which generates the approriate JaveScript-Snippet.

My problem is though, that the JaveScript-Snippet generated by this `TriggerBehaviour` would have to be run **after** the JaveScript-Snippets of **all** the `RegisterBehaviour` on a page and in all components have been run. I know that HeaderItems can have dependencies but this mechanism seems to target the case, when I want some kind of common library loaded (like jQuery) or code executed *before* my custom code. To use this for my case, I'd have to somehow find all `RegisterBehaviours` on the fly that are being added to the current render phase of the page and dynamicly add them as dependencies to the `TriggerBehaviour`, so they run before the `TriggerBehaviours` JavaScript. I see no way though, how to get such a list of all HeaderItems of a certain type.

Any tips on how to approach this problem, either in Wicket or JavaScript?

(Using Java 8 and Wicket 8.9.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FilteredHeaderItem.

Both RegisterBehaviour and TriggerBehaviour will contribute their header items wrapped in `FilteredHeaderItem`s.

In your HTML template you will use two placeholders for the two filters:

```
<div id="registerFilter"></div>
<div id="triggerFilter"></div>
```

The browsers execute the JavaScripts from top to bottom so the trigger ones will be after the register ones.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm after adding `HeaderResponseContainers` for both your mentioned placeholders in my Wicket Page and setting the `FilteringHeaderResponse` as `HeaderResponseDecorator` in my Wicket Application